# SSPI, Treat wrong credentials as anonymous user

Tags: active-directory, apache-2.4, authentication, httpd.conf

I'm running apache 2.4 with xampp, and so far my sspi works well with `mod_authnz_sspi`.

I would like to accept all users, but get their name in `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` if they are in my active directory to display some more tabs.

---

I'm currenlty accepting both users that are in my active directory and anonymous users with `Require valid-user`, but if a user isn't in my AD, or enters wrong credentials, or is on a raspberry I would like to treat him as an anonymous user, but apache currently rejects the connection because of the 'Require valid-user'.

I tried adding `Require all granted` on the side, but it takes priority over `Require valid-user`, and I cant retrieve the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` in php.

```
LoadModule authnz_sspi_module modules/mod_authnz_sspi.so

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AuthType SSPI
    SSPIDomain X.X.X.X
    SSPIAuth on
    SSPIOfferSSPI on
    SSPIAuthoritative on
    SSPIPerRequestAuth on
    SSPIOmitDomain on
    SSPIUsernameCase lower

    #Require all granted
    Require valid-user

</Directory>
```

---

Is it possible to retireve `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` while still accepting all connections ?

Comment: I've done something like this in .NET. You could probably replicate it. I just recently described how I did it to someone else in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76484330/1202807

Comment: I like the idea, not really needing a login page, but in my header sending an ajax request that may set a cookie if apache accepts the connection may work, Thanks !
(However it kinda feels like a hack and i cant imagine there is no clean way to do it with apache directives)